# Ionic Crud and MEAN stack sever

Tags: node.js, mongodb, ionic-framework

I am totally new to ionic framework, currently I'm reading Ionic in action book, which i find really interesting. I've developed web apps with MEAN stack and Im a really big fun of that framework. I'm wondering though, how a form from Ionic can be submitted to a nodejs server? There's no tutorials on the web so is there any books I could read in order for me to build an ionic single page app with a form which will post the fields of the form to nodejs & mongodb?

Comment: The ionic app talks to the node server just like any other client app.

Comment: An Ionic app uses AngularJS to build everything out. You communicate to your Node.js back-end through the use of HTTP Requests by using the `$http` service provided by Angular. There are different ways to implement `$http` in your Angular code and because of that I believe that this question is far too broad. You should continue to read the book and learn more about the approach to service calls in Angular. If after that you have a more specific question you should post a question on StackOverflow.

Comment: To begin with, thank you for your reply. The problem is that every book I got for Ionic (Ionic in action, Learning Ionic and Ionic cookbook) gets into too much detail about the functionalities Ionic has to offer(like geolocation, native functionalities, camera, authorization etc.) instead of performing siplme operations along a nodejs server and mongodb . You are right though, I think the reason I don't get things right, is cause I'm missing basic Angular knowledge. Thanks for your reply again, I will be coming back, more specificaly on this topic .